# Existence of $k$-regular trees with $n$ vertices

Tags: graph-theory

a $k$-regular tree is a tree for which all vertices have a degree of $k$ or $1$ (internal veritces have a degree of $k$ and the leaves have a degree of $1$).

I've been asked to find for which values of $n$ there exists a $k$-regular trees on $n$ vertices.

I can prove that a $k$-regular **graph** on $n$ vertices exists if $n$ is even, or $k$ is even, but not if both are odd. but I'm having hard times finding a sufficient and necessary condition for an existence of $k$-regular tree.

I'm looking for the most simple proof, using the most basic theorems as possible.

Thank!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the tree has $m$ vertices of degree $k$ and $n-m$ vertices of degree $1$, then by the Handshakking lemma

$$km+(n-m) =\sum \mbox{degree} = 2 \mbox{ no edges} = 2n-2 $$

This proves that

$$(k-1)m=n-2$$

thus $k-1$ must divide $n-2$.

You also need to prove that if this is the case, it is possible to build such a tree....But this is easy.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. that's look now very simple, I've thinking about this for hours, tried to approach from many ways. And yes, I need to show how to build such a tree but with your help I'll try to do it myself :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean labeled vertices (since all $k$-regular trees are isomorphic, so if you don't label the vertices there will be just one). Did you study the [Prüfer code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_sequence)? If yes, then you should know that counting those trees is the same as counting words of length $n-2$, constructed from $n$ such that every letter that appears in the word - appears exactly $k-1$ times. Hence there exists a $k$-regular tree on $n$ vertices if and only if $k-1$ divides $n-2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't study Prüfer code, but I did study Cayley's formula, if it has something to do with it.

Comment: Yes, it has a lot to do with it :-) look at the wikipedia link.